# How To Create Headers For A List

Tags: variable, ifelse, loop

I have a list of items. Each item has a season. 
I am trying to organize the items by season. I believe the list is pre sorted and I need to create a header everytime there item has a new season

In php I would imagine something like this

```
$nextSeason = "";
foreach($list as $item){
    $season = $item->season;
    if($nextSeason != $season){
        $nextSeason = $season;
        echo '<h1>' . $season . '</h1>'
    }
}
```

I have no clue how to accomplish this within the EE templating language

Here is the current code looping through the list:

```
{exp:stash:get_list:1 name="classes"
    against="class_category_ids"
    match="#(^|\&|\s){category_id}(.|$)#"
    prefix="classes"
}

    <div class="col-sm-3 class-info-container">
      {classes:class_card}
    </div>
{/exp:stash:get_list:1}
```

If i add `{classes:season}` it is printing out the season for every item.

I also do not understand what the `:1` is at the end of `{exp:stash:get_list:1}` I have looked at the documentation for stash but it does not have a reference for this.

I believe this site is running EE 2

Answer (score 0):

Tough to tell without the whole setting/getting picture, but definitely possible to recreate the effect of your php example with Stash. See: https://gist.github.com/croxton/6219973 
for an example of setting and getting headers and also the individual items for each header. It should apply to what you're trying to do. Also: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Lists#three-and-more-dimensional-lists

The ending ":1" in the module tag is probably used because that stash get_list is within another stash tag pair. You can use any word (like "nested1", "nest2", "bubba" etc...) to differentiate each nested stash tag pair. I believe it's necessary due to the way eecms process module tags, but can't remember for sure.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to go through that example and make it work for my needs.

I have tried using stash:get/set but it was not working very well.

the `get_list` already has a `match` on it, can I use multiple `matches`? A `match` is needed to implement the example `gist`